# Is there any way to check "Path or file exists" in pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

In my hadoop environment, the output directories getting created dynamically. Hence I want to read that output  directories dynamically like, if there is path or file exists do this, otherwise in else do this. So Is there any way to check "Path or file exists" in pig script.??

Comment: You can execute shell command from inside Pig. I would do ls on the directory and check if it exists in shell script.

Comment: Hey Gaurav thnx for the reply, Im trying below code with both sh and bash in pig script but its not working.

sh -mv /user/liddev/desh/locationid/data/cdc/BUILDINGMATCHAUTOMATIC/2014-09-05_011203/part-m-* /user/liddev/desh/locationid/data/cdc/BUILDINGMATCHAUTOMATIC/2014-09-05_011203/PIVID_LID_BID2.txt

bash -mv /user/liddev/desh/locationid/data/cdc/BUILDINGMATCHAUTOMATIC/2014-09-05_011203/part-m-* /user/liddev/desh/locationid/data/cdc/BUILDINGMATCHAUTOMATIC/2014-09-05_011203/PIVID_LID_BID2.txt

Comment: Shell scripts are generally executed inside Pig by surrounding the shell command with ticks. e.g. I have a variable initialization as below:
%default yesterday `date --date="yesterday - 1 day" +"%Y%m%d"`
I was suggesting you to create a variable which based on presence or absence of the path initialized with particular value (say 0 for path absent and 1 for path present) and then use the value of the variable in your pig script

Answer (score 2):

In Pig, you can run a shell command to test whether a path exists and if so return that path else return some other empty data path that is always available.  Then rely on Pig's parameter replacement.

For example:

```html
%declare emptyPath '/user/me/emptyData.csv'
%declare requestedPath '/user/me/realData.csv'
%declare actualPath `sh -c "hdfs dfs -test -e '$requestedPath '; if [ \\$? -eq 0 ]; then echo '$requestedPath '; else echo '$emptyPath '; fi"`

a = load '$actualPath' using PigStorage(',') as (line:chararray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. You can check use Hadoop Shell command like [test](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html%23test) to check whether a path exists but you can not alter you Pig script flow based on that.

I've used [Python](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/cont.html%23embed-python) with Pig to do things you described you want to do in your question.

Comment: Thank you Mikko to repond, I have found the solution of my problem in Oozie workflow. Thank you once again